# Is there a way to monitor DOM changes in a Https context like Google Chrome DevTool does it?

Tags: javascript, dom, https, google-chrome-devtools

I´d like to log certain DOM changes of a browser window at runtime where I play an online card game. When I take a look at Google Chrom Devtools I can see the card base64 encoded data:image/svg+xml items. Is there a way to get these items for further process like writing them to a file ?

I tried to write a Chrome extension with Mutation Observers but following approach threw an error in method observer.observe(target, config) telling me target was not a node...

Css-Class "deck_by" is only used in the body tag of the site...I expected all DOM changes monitored recursively

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var target = $(".deck_by"); 

      // Create an observer instance
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

          console.log("mutation change in ", mutation.type, " name: ",mutation.target);
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({'Mutation': mutation})

        });
      });

      // Configuration of the observer
      var config = { attributes:true, subtree: true, childList: true };

      console.log(target);

      // Pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
      observer.observe(target, config);

    });
```

[DevTools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOYku.jpg)

Comment: your `target` is not an HTML node, effectively, it's a jQuery object. Try with `var target = $(".deck_by")[0];`. It's just a test, though, if you have multiple elements with class `deck_by`, you'll have to loop on target to add observers

Comment: Unfortunately ```var target = $(".deck_by")[0];``` does return 'undefined'

Comment: If you can't specify an existing element, observe `document.body` ..?

Comment: That´s what I do:

Comment: ```<body style="" class="deck_by">```

Comment: That contradicts your comment: "_`$(".deck_by")[0];` does return 'undefined'_". Unless you're adding the class after running this code.

Comment: Sorry...you are right...with document.body html element is initialized [ init(1) ] but still I get the same error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (content.js:23)"

Comment: Solved the problem: ```var target = $(".deck_by")[0]``` was part of the solution but setting ```"run_at": "document_start"``` to  ```"run_at": "document_end"``` in the "content_scripts" section of the manifest.json was crucial :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the "content_scripts" section in the manifest.json from "run_at" : "document_start" to "document_end"